# In chrome dev mode, 'Elements' section doesn't expand sometimes

Tags: google-chrome

Recently(less than 2 months I guess) I encounter error on chrome DEV MODE. In first 'Elements' tab, HTML DOM sometimes doesn't expand so that I have to refresh the page until it expands all elements.

I'm using chrome version 66.0.3359.181 in Sierra.

Anyone suffered & solved this problem or knows why this happens?